# Where does sudoer reports go?

Tags: centos, sudo

So I'm testing out a small CentOS build (rackspace cloud). I set up my user and went to do some sudo'ing. Well, I forgot the step to add my user to the sudoers file with visudo. So of course, I get this error:

> is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

Never saw it before, so now I'm wondering. Where does this get reported? Does it just get sent to mail, or is it logged somewhere?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It will typically get logged `/var/log/secure`, and mail will be sent to `root` on the local system.  You can control this behavior in your `/etc/sudoers` file.  There are a suite of `mail_*` configuration options that determine when `sudo` sends out mail, and there are additional options that control how it logs to syslog.

Answer (score 16):

[image: XKCD]
Source: http://xkcd.com/838/

(for the real answer, look at *larsks*'s answer instead).

Comment: hah, looks like i'm getting coal for christmas this year :(